# Spring boot difference between executable war and jar

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a simple spring boot application with a few controllers. It also serves static files from my webapps directory. So when I deploy it i go to localhost:8080/ and I get my index.html from my webapp/ dir.

When I change the packaging to 'jar' in my pom.xml, and then again access localhost:8080/, it does not fetch the index.html file.
I want to gain deeper understanding of why does this happen, does .war extention automatically enable serving of static files? If so is configured by spring boot? Or maybe it's the embedded tomcat handling jar's and war's differently?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>lt.tomasirruta</groupId>
    <artifactId>wedding</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>wedding</name>
    <description>WeddingApp</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start.class>lt.tomasirruta.WeddingApplication</start.class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start.class}</mainClass>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

read the follwing link. It is explained where to put static files in Spring Boot:
[Static web content](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)

Try to put your index.html under resources/public